# How to solve this error "NotServedByPagesError"

Tags: dns, github-pages, cname, website-hosting

I am working on setting up a custom domain for a GitHub pages website and I have everything set up but on GitHub pages settings with the A records and CNAME records.

But, I have the following error;

`ekenestan.com` is improperly configured Domain does not resolve to the GitHub Pages server. For more information, see Learn more (NotServedByPagesError). We recommend you add an A record pointing to our IP addresses, or an ALIAS record pointing to ivory222.github.io

Please help: